# Cookie passed when expected

Tags: authentication, rust, cookies, jwt, rust-axum

So I'm writing a server with axum rust. In most my other programming languages I normally just bring in package that kinda handles most the jwt claims for me and I just pass it the stuff and tell it 'hey use these values in the cookie'.

When I call '/api/user/login' I get the cookie assigned as expected. I then get the cookie passed properly to all routes that are at '/api/user/*'. However, the browser DOES not pass the cookie to any other subpaths. So '/api/file/upload' the browser DOES NOT pass the cookie.

I've tried SameSite None, Lax, and Strict and none of them work. I thought cookies were supposed to be passed to ALL items on the same domain. What else do I have to do to enable the cookie to be passed properly to all methods on the domain?

```rs
    pub fn token_to_header(&self,token: String) -> AppendHeaders<[(HeaderName, std::string::String); 1]> {

        let auth_cookie = Cookie::build("Authorization", format!("Bearer {}",token))
        .same_site(SameSite::Strict)
        .max_age(cookie::time::Duration::seconds(self.ttl))
        .secure(true)
        .http_only(true)
        .finish()
        ;

        return AppendHeaders([
            (SET_COOKIE,auth_cookie.stripped().to_string())
        ]);
    }
```

I think it has something to do with access control headers but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ah i never realized cookies had a path parameter. You need to set the scoped path. The browser by default uses 1 path up the domain so if you did `/api/login` you would get access to `/api` but it can also be manually set.

```rs
    pub fn token_to_header(&self,token: String) -> AppendHeaders<[(HeaderName, std::string::String); 1]> {

        let auth_cookie = Cookie::build("Authorization", format!("Bearer {}",token))
        .same_site(SameSite::Lax)
        .max_age(cookie::time::Duration::seconds(self.ttl))
        .path("/api")
        .secure(true)
        .http_only(true)
        .finish()
        ;

        return AppendHeaders([
            (SET_COOKIE,auth_cookie.to_string())
        ]);
    }
```